# Difference between CoreProperty object, a ProfileTypeProperty object, and a ProfileSubtypeProperty

Tags: user-profile

What is the different between this type of properties in easy words?

- CoreProperty,
- ProfileTypeProperty,
- ProfileSubtypeProperty